# WPF, Using BitmapImage as image source for display - creates GC pressure

Tags: wpf, performance, garbage-collection, bitmapimage

I am processing images and displaying them one after the other, using BitmapImage as image source for xaml image object. THe problem is that the GC is working non stop and the cause is the BitmapImage.StreamSource which probably is not freed (according to other links - e.g https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/46bab672-c65c-4194-96ba-03f3cfc32fa4/bitmapimagestreamsource-decodepixelwidth-amp-memory-consumption?forum=windowswic). Also by using **StreamSource **and not **UriSource **it seems that the function DecodePixelWidth does not work. Any suggestions what's the best way to display the images without having GC pressure?

I do the following: get byte[] of the processed image data and I use a converter - ByteArrayToBitmapImageConverter:
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
byte[]? imageByteArray = value as byte[];
if (imageByteArray == null) return null!;
var img = new BitmapImage();

```
        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray))
        {
            img.BeginInit();
            img.StreamSource = stream;
            img.DecodePixelWidth = 640;
            img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; 
            img.EndInit();

        }
        return img;

    }
```

The byte[] itself is freed in the calling function(actually I use ArrayPool , but the img.StreamSource seems to cause the problem

Comment: You may also add `img.Freeze()`

Comment: Yeah this one is tough. WPF is not good about freeing image resources promptly or efficiently. If you need very high performance graphics WPF offers D3DImage which uses Direct3D and gives you much more control over the native resources, but there's a lot of code overhead needed to use it.

Comment: I tried the img.Freez() too in one of my trys... Didn't change. Is it possible to use Media element instead for images? Basically I'm using LibVlcSharp to read video file and catch the frames and process them - but got stuck on the display

Comment: So you're displaying every processed frame one at a time in a WPF image, is that right? And I assume we're talking about hundreds or thousands then?  In that case I do have to recommend D3DImage. Note you can use it without C++ using SharpDX.

Comment: Seems SharpDX is no longer under maintenance. I found a solution candidate with MemoryMappedFile

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which I still need to adopt to my needs but seems working. I looked at the code of VlcVideoSourceProvider+ VlcControl which uses it and used the same logic.
Basically what it does is create a MemoryMappedFile and view and attach ImageSource to the file section. This ImageSource is connected (dependency property) to the VlcControl that has an Image oject...

```
 _inpMemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(null, size);
    var handle = _inpMemoryMappedFile.SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle();


    this.dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        this.VideoSource = (InteropBitmap)Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection(handle,
            (int)Width, (int) Height, pixelFormat, Pitch, 0);
    }));


    _inpMemoryMappedView = _inpMemoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor();
    var viewHandle = _inpMemoryMappedView.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
```

Seems to work fine.